# Rails 3 best way to write an IN clause in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This works:

```
scope :archived, :conditions => "day_id IN (#{Day.where("year_id != #{DateTime.now.year}").collect{ |d| d.id }.join(",")})"
```

Is there a more railsy way to write IN clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple re-write you could do something like following

```
scope :archived, where( :day_id => Day.where("year_id != #{DateTime.now.year}").collect{ |d| d.id }
```

But this will generate two queries and unncessary join from your rails code. Ideally you should do this join through SQL and do the check in one query only.

So resulting model should be something like following

```
class Model

  belongs_to :day

  scope :archieved, joins(:day).where("days.year_id != #{DateTime.now.year}")

end
```

See following for more info

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: You overlooked the hidden bug. What happens if the Model class is loaded at 23:00 on Dec31 but the scope is used at 02:00 on Jan1?

Answer (score 3):

There's a hidden bug in your original scope and amitamb's solution. `scope` is a class method so why you say this:

```
scope :blahblah, arguments
```

the `arguments` expression is evaluated while the class is being parsed and loaded. In particular, `DateTime.now.year` will be evaluated when the class is being loaded into the Rails environment. Consequently, if the class is loaded on 2012-12-31, then the `where` will be:

```
where('days.year_id != 2012')
```

and if you use the scope a few hours later on 2013-01-01, it will still be using 2012 as the year. There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Use a class method or lambda for the scope:

   ```
   scope :archived, -> { joins(:day).where('days.year_id != ?', DateTime.now.year) }
   # or
   def self.archived
       joins(:day).where('days.year_id != ?', DateTime.now.year)
   end
   ```
2. Push the current year computation down into the database:

   ```
   scope :archived, joins(:day).where('days.year_id != extract(year from current_date)')
   ```

Some databases will want something instead of `extract(year from current_date)` so you might want to go with **(1)** to avoid the possible portability and timezone problems.

Also, your original approach suffers similar problems with the `Day.where(...)` part, that query is executed while your class is being loaded so if the `days` table changes while your application is running, then you'll be checking the wrong list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
your_logic = "year_id != #{DateTime.now.year}".collect{ |d| d.id }.join(",")}
scope :archived, :conditions => Day.where(your_logic)["day_id"]
```

I just replaced the `day_id IN` by accessing the object first then pulling out `day_id`.